# Why do sefardim have the minchag of using the mothers name on the tombstone and when praying for the deceased?

Tags: minhag, death, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, cemetery-grave

I was told that the sefardi custom, based on the Chida, is to use the mother's name of the deceased when praying for the deceased and on the tombstone.

For example: Moshe was born to Sarah and Yaakov; the name Moshe ben Sarah would be written on the tombstone.

Where can this Chida be found and what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: I have seen the custom brought down in the sefer pnei baruch and gesher hachaim that write that sefardim have this custom - but neither of them mention the Chida as a source?

Comment: @Dov, do you remember if the reason for this custom was brought down?

Comment: In both instances it just says that sefardim write the name of the mother.